# MySQL 8 slow with descending composite index

Tags: mysql, indexing, composite-index

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
      shows.id, 
      shows.title, 
      shows.thumbnail, 
      shows.views, 
      shows.likes, 
      shows.dislikes, 
      shows.duration, 
      shows.hd, 
      shows.origin, 
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(shows.upload_date) as upload_date 
   FROM 
      shows 
   WHERE 
          (shows.views, shows.id) < (0, 272990) 
      and shows.visible = 1 
   ORDER BY 
      shows.views DESC, 
      shows.id DESC 
   LIMIT 
      32
```

It takes around 0.8 seconds in MySQL 8.0.15.

I have tried indexes like this:

```
CREATE INDEX views_desc_id_desc_visible ON shows (views desc, id desc, visible)
```

As well as ones like this:

```
CREATE INDEX views_desc_id_desc ON shows (views desc, id desc)
```

And many other permutations. I've deleted them and redid it from scratch many times. Visible does have an index on itself.

When I do expain I see it only doing "Using where" while using a key called views_desc_id_desc_visible. Removing visible from the query doesn't change it's performance. Removing the two desc  (so: order by views, id) does make it 0.0008 seconds.

Why isn't this going faster?

**Update**  (copied from Comment)

```
SELECT  shows.id, shows.title, shows.thumbnail, shows.views, shows.likes,
        shows.dislikes, shows.duration, shows.hd, shows.origin,
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(shows.upload_date) as upload_date
    FROM  shows
    WHERE      (shows.views <= 0)
      and  not (shows.views  = 0 and shows.id >= 272990)
      and  visible = 1
    ORDER BY  shows.views DESC, shows.id DESC
    LIMIT  32
```

fixes it.  I just don't know why using that otherway ignores indexes.

Comment: Seems it is related to this: (shows.views,shows.id) < (0, 272990)

Comment: SELECT shows.id, shows.title, shows.thumbnail, shows.views, shows.likes, shows.dislikes, shows.duration, shows.hd, shows.origin, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(shows.upload_date) as upload_date FROM shows WHERE (shows.views <= 0) and not (shows.views = 0 and shows.id >= 272990) and visible = 1 ORDER BY shows.views DESC, shows.id DESC LIMIT 32 fixes it. I just don't know why using that otherway ignores indexes.

Comment: Can `views` be negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`visible` must come *first* in the index.

```
INDEX(visible, views DESC, id DESC)
```

The general rule for building the optimal index is:

1. Include all columns in the `WHERE` that are tested with `= constant`.
2. Then other columns.

More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

There is a *possible* issue with the "row constructor" you are using with `WHERE (shows.views, shows.id) < (0, 272990)`.  That was essentially not optimized at all until 5.7.

The workaround (pre-5.7) was that the complicated expression you mentioned in your Comment was optimized.  It is probably still optimized:

```
WHERE      (shows.views <= 0)
  and  not (shows.views  = 0 and shows.id >= 272990)
```

8.0 introduced honoring `DESC` in index declarations.

I am worried that the Optimizer has failed to put those two enhancements together to do what you are looking for.

Please show us `EXPLAIN SELECT...` for your attempts.  Look especially at `Key_len`.

Even without 8.0, I would recommend

```
INDEX(visible, views, id)
```

In this case, the index can be traversed backwards to handle

```
WHERE visible = 0
  AND ...
ORDER BY views DESC, id DESC
```

That is assuming that the row constructor issues are resolved.